# Code Coverage during Integration tests

Tags: testing, integration-testing, code-coverage

I am looking for some tool that can tell code coverage of tests that execute in integrated environment. I have my web service application deployed as war in tomcat and which again talks to database. The tests invoke the web service endpoints for testing the functionality. Now , I want some tool which can tell the code coverage of my tests.

I would like to mention that we already have cobertura tool for our unit tests.

I am searching for such integration test coverage tool and would appreciate if someone in this forum can throw some light.

Many Thanks,
Tejas.

Comment: Why doesn't cobertura satisfy your needs?

Comment: Ira Baxter : Please check the comment in response to post below.

Comment: Well, looks like cobertura can work for the code coverage test scenario I am looking for. I have just started reading article http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/instrumentingDeploymentArtifact.html and "Overview" section describes the exact scenario.